# log4j: SocketAppender and network link down

Tags: sockets, log4j, apache-chainsaw

I have a Java application that use log4j. 
The application run on a linux server. I can (with script) add socket appender in the server. 
I use the log viewer Chainsaw. This log viewer works on my computer (on windows XP)

I follow step below :

- Open Chainsaw (on my computer) and configure it to simpleSocketReceiver
- Open a Socket Appender (server) to connect to chainsaw.
- Disconnect my computer from network.
- With a second computer : try to connect to the server : can't connect to him
- On the first computer : chainsaw was bloked (except if reconnection delay of socket appender is set to 0)
- Reconnection of my computer to the network
- With the second computer : the connection is now possible.

I don't know why the second computer can't connect to the server.

If anyone can help me ^^

Thanks a lot

Shina